# Java servlet. Почему не работают wait()/notifyAll()?

Tags: servlet, gwt, eclipse, java

Я только начинаю изучать Java и в том числе сервлеты. Использую Eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 2) и GWT. Написал простой тест (без GAE). Клиент на GWT отправляет запросы серверу. Один из запросов делает `wait()`, а другой (во время, когда первый висит на wait) вызывает `notifyAll()`.

Никакой реакции.

Тот, что вызвал `wait()` `(f3Server())` **продолжает ждать до заданного таймаута**, после чего возвращает клиенту результат.
Тот, что вызывал `notify` `(f2Server())` успешно возвращает результат. Результаты вызова нормально отображаются. Количество таких запросов (`wait` в параллель (в приведенном тексте вывода этого теста нет)) ни на что не влияет.

```
Date update = new Date();

public String f2Server(String []input) {  // 'Будильник'
    priln("f2Serveer: "+Thread.currentThread().toString()+" id="+input[2]);

    update = new Date();
    synchronized (update) {
        update.notifyAll();
    }
    return Thread.currentThread().toString()+
        " f2Server, "+input[0]+"<br>Arg: "+input[1]+"<br>"+
        (input.length > 2? input[2]:"");
}

public String f3Server(String []input) {  // Ждет события

    priln("f3Server: "+Thread.currentThread().toString()+" id="+input[2]);
    Date d = new Date();
    try {
        /*
        while (d.getTime() > update.getTime()) {
            Thread.sleep(500);      
        }
        */
        synchronized (update) {
            update.wait(5000);
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        priln("f3Server sleep exception "
                +Thread.currentThread().toString()+" id="+input[2]);
    }
    priln("f3server after sleep "
            +Thread.currentThread().toString()+" id="+input[2]);
    return Thread.currentThread().toString()+
        " f3Server, "+input[0]+"<br>Arg: "+input[1]+"<br>"+
        (input.length > 2? input[2]:"");
}
```

Отладочная печать на консоли:

```
f2Serveer: Thread[btpool0-0,5,main] id=1313503727340
f3Server: Thread[btpool0-0,5,main] id=1313503727340
f2Serveer: Thread[btpool0-2,5,main] id=1313503727340
f2Serveer: Thread[btpool0-2,5,main] id=1313503727340
f2Serveer: Thread[btpool0-2,5,main] id=1313503727340
f3server after sleep Thread[btpool0-0,5,main] id=1313503727340
```

Переменная **update** действительно одна и та же для всех вызовов, что подтверждается закомментареным тестом `while()` (вместо `synchronized (update)`) в `f3Server()`.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что тут происходит ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вызвали `wait()` на одном объекте

```
synchronized (update) {
    update.wait(5000);
}
```

а `notifyAll()` вызываете на другом:

```
update = new Date();
synchronized (update) {
    update.notifyAll();
}
```

А закомментированный фрагмент работал, поскольку на каждой итерации цикла происходило новое обращение по ссылке `update` и каждый раз вызывался объект, на который в данный момент укаывает эта ссылка. `wait()` же держит блокировку на изначальном объекте.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра обязательно проверю, но чую, что так и есть.

Comment: Проверил, идеально.